# Getting the full path to a file with "readlink -f" does NOT work on OSX?

Tags: linux, macos

On Linux (redhat/ubuntu/you name it), I can do this:

```
$readlink -f myfile.txt
/tmp/local/path/to/myfile.txt
```

On OSX (yosemite):

```
$ readlink -f eclipse-projects.xml 
readlink: illegal option -- f
```

Can someone tell me what's going on?
What's the "equivalent" of `-f` on osx?
(And why do people love to make things sooooo inconsistent?!)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/40144

Comment: OS X is not Linux. It is Unix. ;) You can install GNU `coreutils` via [`brew`](http://brew.sh/) if you want them.

Comment: @DanielB Yeah, I hear ya... but still, some consistency doesn't hurt

Comment: This was answered at length in a different forum: [How can I get the behavior of GNU's readlink -f on a Mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055671/how-can-i-get-the-behavior-of-gnus-readlink-f-on-a-mac)

Comment: @Daniel B Yup, and even more specifically it's very similar to (and based on) BSD. To the OP, Apple specifically loves to make things inconsistent. They actively eschew industry standards. A good example is their SSDs, which are exactly the same as any other SSD but have proprietary pin arrangements and cost 4x as much. I'm pretty sure the 2011 to 2013 style SSDs are literally M.2 connectors with the cutout slot moved to a different location.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Return the canonicalized path (works on OS-X like 'readlink -f' on Linux); . is $PWD
function realpath {
    [ "." = "${1}" ] && n=${PWD} || n=${1}; while nn=$( readlink -n "$n" ); do n=$nn; done; echo "$n"
}
```