# how to find path of a file with terminal in Sierra

Tags: terminal, apache-http-server

Running MacOS Sierra, is there a way to find the path of a file in terminal if you know the file name but not the location? Is there a command like readlink -f in linux that will work in Sierra? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1002825/getting-the-full-path-to-a-file-with-readlink-f-does-not-work-on-osx